# Named route for non resource nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, rails-routing

I'm trying to generate a link for a user to click to confirm their account. I'm wanting this:

```
/users/:id/confirm/:code
```

I've got this in my routes file:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'confirm/:confirmation_code', :action => 'confirm'
  end
end
```

I've tried:

```
user_confirm_path(@user, @confirmation_code)
confirm_user_path(@confirmation_code, @user)
```

and many others but can't seem to get the right one. I guess I could always generate the link url myself but that doesn't seem the rails way.

This is what my rake routes outputs:

```
rake routes
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
       GET    /users/:id/confirm/:confirmation_code(.:format) users#confirm
```

but omits the thing I'm actually looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another similar question which was answered over here: [Named routes inserting a . instead of a /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023884/named-routes-inserting-a-instead-of-a)

Using that same answer for this problem solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not gonna give the solution right away, but I will give you the keys to solve the problem yourself: ("*Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.*")

You can run the following command to list all the available routes in your app and the corresponding helpers:

```
rake routes
```

In my app, there is so many routes I can't see them all at once. So I add a `| grep something` to only select the part that I need. In your case, it would be something like:

```
rake routes | grep confirm
```

And you will probably end up reading an output like:

```
confirm_user_path GET /users/:id/confirm/:confirmation_code
```

---

Googling "**rails 4.0.2 url helper**", first link is a Github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12751

Comment: Believe it or not, I've tried that. I'll update my question because I can't format it here

Comment: Can you try to use `confirm_user_path(user_id: @user.id, confirmation_code: @confirmation_code)` ?

Comment: Still `undefined method `confirm_user_path'`

Comment: Did you restart your server? That's weird.. What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I died a bit inside when I realised I hadn't restarted the server, but having done that, it still doesn't work. Using Rails 4.0.2

Comment: Googling "rails 4.0.2 url helper", first link is a Github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12751

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48086/discussion-between-mike-t-and-mryoshiji)

Comment: I upgraded to rails 4.0.3 but still no luck